# Run orderly and parallel in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

How can I make a program in Python running like this:

`main():
task 1 --> task 2 --> (task 3, task 4) --> task 5`

Explanation: I run task 1, then task 2. After finishing task 2, task 3 and task 4 run parallel.
After finishing task 3, task 4 immediately finish. Then task 5 run.

I tried

```
try:
   thread.start_new_thread.task3
   thread.start_new_thread.task4
except:
    print " Unable to run "
```

but it worked like that:

`task 1 --> task 2 --> task 5` (task 3 and task 4 worked from program started and finished) ^_^

Comment: put the try after task 2 and before task 5. and before task 5, remember to join them.

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can create threads with precedences by calling `join`. Threads will be locked until the previous threads finish. Remember you cannot call join on threads which have not started. `task1` to `task5` are the actual procedures to invoke (normal procedures you MUST define).

To make task4 finish when task3 finishes, create a global variable and make task4 watch that variable. task3 must set a value that task4 must be waiting for. That's up to you on how to do it but there's no built-in mechanism for that. If you don't want global variables, then use many of the well-known python mechanisms to avoid that (e.g. each callable could be an instance's bound method).

```
class CustomThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(group=None, target=None, name=None, prev=(), args=(), kwargs={}):
        super(CustomThread, self).__init__(group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self.prev_threads = prev

    def run():
        for prev in self.prev_threads:
            prev.join()
        super(CustomThread, self).run()

try:
    thread1 = CustomThread(target=task1)
    thread2 = CustomThread(prev=[thread1], target=task2)
    thread3 = CustomThread(prev=[thread2], target=task3)
    thread4 = CustomThread(prev=[thread2], target=task4)
    thread5 = CustomThread(prev=[thread3,thread4], target=task5)
    #start the threads in this order or you'll get a RuntimeError
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    thread4.start()
    thread5.start()
except:
    print " unable to run "
```

Comment: That's an interesting setup! Your order of starting the threads is the obvious, logical one, but suppose you started thread 2 before 1 — why wouldn't that work?  It seems that thread 2 would block waiting for thread 1 to finish, wouldn't it?

Comment: Because if you do so, you'll get a RuntimeError;

Comment: You cannot join a thread that has not started. doing so raises a runtime error. that's why the order

Comment: OK; is that because you can only join started threads, not threads that have been created but not started? —— I see the answer is "Yes".  +1, BTW.  May I suggest adding this as extra information to the answer.  We can then clean the comments up.

Comment: That's right. joining a thread that has not been created is an intrinsic nonsense xD (you'll get -in the best case- a NameError on the variable), but joining a created thread that has not been started yields a RuntimeError and has that only meaning, so if you fall in that, you'll know it's because of a join.

Comment: Thanks so much for your helps and comments. I will try this code. It looks like the thing I have expected.